# How to get the parent nodes and adjacent nodes using xpath and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing code to scrape github.I have the below dom tree extracted from the view source page.

```
<tr>
    <td class="blob-num blob-num-addition empty-cell"></td>

    <td id="diff-e07a5ab360bd8cfa1490cbe9056ade49R298" data-line-number="298"
        class="blob-num blob-num-addition js-linkable-line-number"></td>

  <td class="blob-code blob-code-addition">

    <span class="blob-code-inner">+    <span class="pl-k">@PostAuthorize</span>(<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>this.belongsToTenant(returnObject) &amp;&amp; (hasAnyRole(&#39;ROLE_ADMIN_INVOICE&#39;,&#39;ROLE_RUN_AS_ADMIN_INVOICE&#39;) or this.belongsToUser(returnObject, authentication.name))<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</span>

  </td>
</tr>
```

I am able to get the node containing "PostAuthorize" using the below xpath query.

```
//span[contains(.,'PostAuthorize')]
```

I want to get to the node containing the word "data-line-number" so that I can extract the line number value from this attribute. Also, I want to traverse to the parent node from the current node.How do I do this? One approach could be to get the parent node and then go through all the child nodes to find the required child element. But How do I do this in xpath?

Comment: The link I sent you in my answer is rather comprehensive, it includes both Css selector and Xpath. Please post comment here if you have further questions.

Comment: well..I was able to get the line number as well using //span[contains(.,'@PostAuthorize')]/../..

Answer (score 0):

There are two common techniques, Xpath and CSS selector, but in this case, you can only use Xpath, as CSS selector does not support navigating backwards.

In your case, you need to look for "PostAuthorize"'s parent, which is "blob-code blob-code-addition", then look for "blob-code blob-code-addition"'s parent, which is a tr element, from there, you are free to find this element you want by using Xpath or CSS selector, if you want to extract its attribute value, in python, I use "element.get_attribute()" method, I am sure in Java, there is an equivalent.

Please refer to this document for more information. It is really comprehensive.
http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf

Look for this term:"Parent of Element ".

Hope it helps.